# Firewall Benchmark, Checklist, Guideline?

Tags: firewalls, hardening

I'm doing some research on checklist, benchmark, hardening guidelines. And I couldn't find specific documents for security checklist for firewall.

CIS had this [document](https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/cisco/CIS_Cisco_Firewall_Benchmark_v3.0.2.pdf), but it was only for Cisco firewall, and also one for Checkpoint firewall.

And I found another one from NIST, named "Guidelines on Firewalls, policy", which was for configuration.

SANS got [this](https://www.sans.org/media/score/checklists/FirewallChecklist.pdf) nice document of Firewall Checklist, but I'm afraid it's too old, as all the info's are from 2000-2001. Are there any checklist, benchmarking kind of "standard", guide, material?

Comment: The problem with the SANS list isn't so much that it's outdated as that it comes from a "default permit" mindset rather than a "default deny" mindset.

Comment: Firewalls vary greatly in function and technology. It might not be possible to have a general hardening guide, except to ensure appropriate user access and access to config UI.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://securityskeptic.typepad.com/the-security-skeptic/firewall-best-practices-egress-traffic-filtering.html) a good one on filtering your egress traffic.

And [here's](http://cdn.swcdn.net/creative/v9.3/pdf/Whitepapers/Best_Practices_for_Effective_Firewall_Management.pdf) a whitepaper put out by a firewall provider (they start the sales pitch on page 6, but the rest before it is solid advice).

[This](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc995156.aspx) is Microsoft's take on the matter.

[This](http://www.principlelogic.com/docs/firewall_best_practices.pdf) is a document written by Kevin Beaver, an infosec professional.

Cover all the bases? :)